# Using PHP to update file after a new copy is uploaded

Tags: php

So I'm trying to see if something like this is possible WITHOUT using database.

1. A file is uploaded to the server /files/file1.html
2. PHP is tracking the upload time by checking last update time in database
3. If the file (file1.html) has been updated since the last DB time, PHP makes changes; Otherwise, no changes are made

Basically, for a text simulation game (basketball), it outputs HTML files for rosters/stats/standings/etc. and I'd like to be able to insert each team's Logo at the top (which the outputted files don't do).  Obviously, it would need to be done often as the outputted files are uploaded to the server daily.  I don't want to have to go through each team's roster manually inserting images at the top.

***Don't have an example as the league hasn't started.***

I've been thinking of just creating a button on the league's website (not created yet) that when pushed would update the pages, but I'm hoping to have PHP do it by itself.

Comment: Isn't the upload time always going to be after the update time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could simply let php check for the file creation date (the point in time where the file was created on the server, not the picture itself was made). check http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php and you should be done within 30mins ;)

sexy quick & dirty unproven code:

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
$timestamp_now = time(); // get timestamp from now (seconds)
if (filemtime($filename) > $timestamp_now) {
   // overwrite the file (maybe check for existing file etc first)
}
```